# Routing direction in Google Maps keep loading at first try

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to open route direction url from my iOS application. But the Google Maps will keep loading for the route direct at the first try.

When I open the url again, it can show the route direction immediately, so I wondering is this the Google Maps issue or my application issue.

I can reproduce this issue with another device and reinstall my application as well as Google Maps.

[The image of route direction keep loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMueM.jpg)

Below is the url that I trying to open:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=3.1466072,101.7116219&directionsmode=driving
```

Below is the code:

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    let urlStr: String = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(long)&directionsmode=driving"
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/my/app/id585027354")!)
}
```

Comment: did you  declare the URL schemes in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I did declare the URL schemes in info.plist, it just didn't worked in first try recently